# How to get HP ALM to run HP UFT scripts remotely on Windows 10 workstation/hosts

Tags: hp-uft, alm, uft14

We currently have UFT 14.03 installed on our workstations/hosts along with ALM 12.50.32 installed on our ALM server.  We have the HP ALM Lab Service installed on the workstations/hosts to allow ALM to connect remotely and run the UFT scripts on them.
I want to upgrade the workstations/hosts to windows 10 (since 7 is quiet old). But I can't seem to find a windows 10 installer for the HP ALM Lab Service.  If there isn't one anymore, how do I get the ALM server to be able to communicate with those workstations/hosts to be able to run the UFT scripts remotely?  I need the same setup/configuration we have now with windows 7 on windows 10.

Comment: what kind of uft scripts are u using? We are executing uft scripts remotely from ALM without lab service.

Answer (score 0):

I actually finally found somewhere online we could get a ALM Lab Service installer for Windows 10 that would work.
https://alm.deloitte.com/qcbin/LabService_index.html
Downloaded the 64 bit, got everything installed and configured on my windows 10 workstation and everything worked!